# Correct way to pass parameters to a Prism popup window

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am using a Prism 6 in a WPF application. 
 
I am using the `RegionPopupBehavior` from [Microsoft's StockTrader example code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Prism-for-WPF-Reference-0f9aa651/sourcecode?fileId=113323&pathId=1081420737)
However, whenever this popup is shown, there appears to be no way to pass parameters the the view. 
- `INavigationAware.OnNavigatedTo` is not called. 
- There isn't a way to get the region parameters for the view without the view specifically knowing the name of the `IRegion` it is in (as far as I know).

What is the correct way for a command to provide parameters to the new view?

Edit:
I am wanting to be able to show the popup window from a command in code. 
The code may not have scope to the actual view class, only it's name.

Comment: Can you add more detail about how you want to implement this? How you want to be able to pass parameters, use a command, why you thought the a region popup behavior would work for you, all of that.

Comment: @Landerah: Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Sorry I didn’t find any nice solution for this. As I mentioned to @R.Richards, the solution in that answer didn’t quite solve this issue. It’s probably because I was trying to use PRISM in a way that it wasn’t supposed to be. I have PRISMed for a while now, perhaps there are new powerful abilities ;)

Comment: @ascholz I’ll just add that the issue is that OnNavigatedTo is only ever called if it’s navigated to after it’s been navigated to at least once. I think I kind of solved it by ‘navigating’ to everything at start up...

Comment: @Landerah: I've found a solution. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use Prism 6, you really need to reference examples that aren't 4 years old, and are likely not to work well with the latest bits.

You can find more recent examples [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf).

Specifically, you will want to look into the Interactivity examples, toward to bottom if the page. This is the what you use now to manage popups for confirmations, notifications and other interactions (getting input from the end users). The [Interactivity - Custom Request](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/blob/master/28-CustomRequest) example maybe exactly what you need. You can use that one to pass information to, and get information from the interaction.

I use these sometimes for showing the end user small edit interactions. I pass the object I want them to edit, and get back the changed object when they click OK, and take action (update/save).

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for these links they look useful. I don't see how it solves my use case though, I'll fill out my question more fully. Essentially, the popup should be able to shown in code, and show view via it's name, not xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Class Notification has a property **Content**,object type.So you can pass any type parameter to Popup Window. For example,In MainViewModel:

```
using Prism.Interactivity.InteractionRequest;
using Prism.Commands;
public InteractionRequest<IConfirmation> ConfirmInPopup { get; private set; }
//code
 ConfirmInPopup.Raise(new Confirmation() {
                        Title = "Confirm",
                        Content = new MedInModel
                        {
                            MedOnlyCode = med.MedOnlyCode,
                            MedName = med.MedName,
                            MedNowAmt=10,
                            BoxId=med.BoxId
                        }
                    },t => 
                            if (t.Confirmed)
                            {

                            }
                         );
```

In the popup window,you can get this from Notification,

```
using Prism.Interactivity.InteractionRequest;
public class ConfirmMedInViewModel : IInteractionRequestAware
{
        public INotification Notification
        {
            get
            {
                return _confirmation;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _confirmation, (IConfirmation)value);
            }
        }
        public Action FinishInteraction { get; set; 
}
```

Now get parameters from Notification property.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to call ShowDialog() when calling the new Windows but only the method Show(). And then this works with the OnNavigatedTo. Because when ShowDialog is called, the MainWindow should be paused. And only after the window is closed, the OnNavigatedTo method is called.